# How to create this Canvas Animation JS

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg, canvas

Does someone know how is this animation build, which js framework is used or something that can help me get to know to recreate something similar?

Banner BG animation ---> https://envylabs.com/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell with what library this animation was build with, because it is hidden in React bundled code, but I can show you a way to do something similar with [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/).

By looking at the animation, it seems that rules are:

- a circle is influenced by mouse pointer if it is under a certain distance from it
- the closest to the mouse pointer a circle is:

  - the bigger it becomes
  - the farther from the window center it goes.

Here is a [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) implementing this.

```
//
// CONSTANTS
//

// user defined
var ROWS_COUNT                = 10;  // number of rows in the grid
var COLUMNS_COUNT             = 10;  // number of columns in the grid
var MOUSE_INFLUENCE_RADIUS    = 350; // maximal distance from mouse pointer to be influenced
var INFLUENCE_SCALE_FACTOR    = 1;   // maximal influence on point scale
var INFLUENCE_POSITION_FACTOR = 15;  // maximal influence on point position

// computed
var STEP_X = view.bounds.width / COLUMNS_COUNT;
var STEP_Y = view.bounds.height / ROWS_COUNT;
var RADIUS = Math.min(STEP_X, STEP_Y) * 0.1;


//
// ITEMS
//

// create a circle for each points in the grid
var circles = [];
for (var i = 0; i < COLUMNS_COUNT; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < COLUMNS_COUNT; j++)
    {
        var gridPoint = new Point((i + 0.5) * STEP_X, (j + 0.5) * STEP_Y);

        circles.push(new Path.Circle({
            center     : gridPoint,
            radius     : RADIUS,
            fillColor  : 'black',
            // matrix application is disabled in order to be able to manipulate scaling property
            applyMatrix: false,
            // store original center point as item custom data property
            data       : {gridPoint: gridPoint}
        }));
    }
}


//
// EVENTS
//

function onMouseMove(event)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++)
    {
        var circle    = circles[ i ];
        var gridPoint = circle.data.gridPoint;
        var distance  = event.point.getDistance(gridPoint);

        // only influence circles that are in mouse influence zone
        if (distance <= MOUSE_INFLUENCE_RADIUS)
        {
            var influence = 1 - distance / MOUSE_INFLUENCE_RADIUS;

            // the closest the circle is from the mouse pointer
            // the bigger it is
            circle.scaling = 1 + influence * INFLUENCE_SCALE_FACTOR;
            // the farthest it is from view center
            circle.position = gridPoint + (gridPoint - view.center).normalize(influence * INFLUENCE_POSITION_FACTOR);
        }
        else
        {
            // reset circle state
            circle.scaling  = 1;
            circle.position = gridPoint;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too open.
But there are some libraries that will save you a lot of time:

- [D3.js](https://d3js.org/)
- [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/)
- [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/)

There are a lot more, but it depends on what you need.